# IOS 6 and Auto Layout custom button height wrong

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

I've created a really simple custom flat button:

```
@implementation HAFlatButton

+ (id)buttonWithColor:(UIColor *)aColor
{
    id button = [super buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button setFlatColor:aColor];

    CGRect frame = [button frame];
    frame.size.height = 200;
    [button setFrame:frame];

    return button;
}

+ (id)defaultButton
{
    return [HAFlatButton buttonWithColor:[HAColors buttonColor]];
}

- (void)setFlatColor:(UIColor *)flatColor
{
    _flatColor = flatColor;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:4.0];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [path addClip];

    [_flatColor setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}

@end
```

When I add a button to my auto layout using [HAFlatButton defaultButton], it's just barely taller than the button text, but when I add a [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] to my layout, it has the proper insets around the label.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you creating your autolayout constraints in code?

Comment: When using auto layout you do not set any frames. All sizing and positioning is done through constraints.

Comment: Yes, I'm creating my auto layout constraints in code, using Masonry.  I wound up setting the height in the constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do one or more of the following:

Add a height constraint.

Override the intrinsicSize return value.

Adjust the vertical content hugging priority.

Comment: So I'm guessing that when I call [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect], UIButtonTypeRoundedRect is setting an intrinsicSize?

Comment: One way to know for sure. Ask the button. Log the result. Lots of UI elements have a computed intrinsic size, particularly things with labels. Get Eric Sadun's new book on autolayout. It's pretty enlightening.